# wicket listview that contains custom condition panel and user can add or remove conditions

Tags: java, listview, wicket, panel

I have a list of conditions. User can add or remove an condition. There is a plus link that adds a condition and a remove link that removes it. When user clicks on add link a form is appearing and s/he can enter condition properties inside it.
I'm using wicket ListView for implementing this component. I have an conditionPanel inside this ListView. When user clicks on add s/he can see another conditionPanel with empty fields. When s/he submits the form a list of conditions are sent to server.
My ListView gets a list of conditions and builds conditionPanel for each of them.
The problem is that when I call listView.getModelObject I expect to get the correct list of conditions, but this is not heppening. I don't know what to do to get the correct list.
Each conditionPanel knows how to build the correct condition.
**java code:**

```
    Form conditionForm = new Form("condition-submit-form");

    final WebMarkupContainer conditions = new WebMarkupContainer("conditions-container");
    conditions.setOutputMarkupId(true);


    final List<ConditionWrapper> conditionsList;

    if(isEditModeIn) {
        conditionsList = alertDefinitionWrapper.getConditions();
    } else {
        conditionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        conditionsList.add(null);
    }


    final IModel<List<ConditionWrapper>> conditionsModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<ConditionWrapper>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<ConditionWrapper> load() {
            return conditionsList;
        }
    };

    final ListView<ConditionWrapper> conditionsListView = new ListView<ConditionWrapper>("conditions", conditionsModel) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<ConditionWrapper> item) {
            ConditionWrapper conditionWrapper = item.getModelObject();
            ConditionPanel conditionPanel = new ConditionPanel("condition", conditionWrapper, alertDefinitionWrapper);
            item.add(conditionPanel);
        }
    };
    conditions.add(conditionsListView);
    conditionForm.add(conditions);

    AjaxSubmitLink addConditionLink = new AjaxSubmitLink("add-new-condition-link", conditionForm) {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            conditionsListView.getModelObject().add(null);
            if(target != null) {
                target.add(conditions);
            }
        }
    };
    addConditionLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
    conditionsListView.setReuseItems(true);

    conditionForm.add(addConditionLink);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <form wicket:id="condition-submit-form">
        <div wicket:id="conditions-container">
            <span wicket:id="conditions">
                <span wicket:id="condition"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <a wicket:id="add-new-condition-link">add</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

For example user clicks on add link and adds another condition by filling its fields and then submits the form. Then I call conditionsModel.getObject I want to get a list which contains the new condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new condition to the conditionsList directly. Then add the ListView to the ajaxtarget and then the listview should be rebuild with the list so including the new item.

In your code you also use a LoadableDetachableModel for the list. This is not necessary like you use it here, use Model.of(conditionsList) instead.

Comment: Add works in my code. The problem is that conditionPanel has fields like text field and radio button. User can fill these fields and then click submit. On submit I want to call conditionsListView.getModelObject and get correct list of conditions. This is not happening. I only get the old list of conditions.